# How can divide two counted columns?

Tags: postgresql, select, divide

I have the following code:

```
SELECT  (
        SELECT COUNT(distinct user_id)
        FROM   re_read
        ) AS re_user_id,
        
        (
        SELECT COUNT(distinct user_id)
        FROM   first_read
        ) AS first_user_id;
```

The result is:

```
re_user_id | first_user_id
--------------------------
     66231 |        210023
```

But I would like to divide this two values and get re_user_id / first_user_id = 0,31535.

How should I do this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is useful thing named [CTE](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cte/).

Using it:

```
with t as (
    SELECT  (
            SELECT COUNT(distinct user_id)
            FROM   re_read
            )::numeric AS re_user_id,
            (
            SELECT COUNT(distinct user_id)
            FROM   first_read
            )::numeric AS first_user_id)
select re_user_id, first_user_id, re_user_id / first_user_id as division from t;
```

Note the type casting in the CTE query.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few ways. Here are two more.
Using `values` and casts:

```
select x, y, x/y ratio from 
(
 values
 (
  (SELECT COUNT(distinct user_id) FROM re_read)::numeric,
  (SELECT COUNT(distinct user_id) FROM first_read)::numeric
 )
) t(x,y);
```

or nested `select` and casts:

```
select x, y, x/y ratio from 
(
 select
  (SELECT COUNT(distinct user_id) FROM re_read)::numeric,
  (SELECT COUNT(distinct user_id) FROM first_read)::numeric
) t(x,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just divide the two values with the `/` operator.

I also multiply by `1.0` to override integer division.

```
SELECT  1.0 * (
        SELECT COUNT(distinct user_id)
        FROM   re_read
        ) 
        /
        (
        SELECT COUNT(distinct user_id)
        FROM   first_read
        ) AS ratio
```

Comment: I have tried to divide in the same way, but I get syntax error:
_ERROR: syntax error at or near "/"
  Position: 112

        /
        ^
1 statement failed._

Comment: @ZoltánDomokos  Sorry.  I left `as re_user_id` in the expression.  It is fixed now in my answer.